# Python pandas- Remove all elements of one dataframe that aren't included in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with two dataframes in pandas:

DF1: Product_ID, Num_Reviews

DF2: Product_ID, Reviewer_ID, Review_Score

I want to remove or filter DF2 to only contain entries with a Product_ID that exists in DF1. I'm not very familiar with pandas or even python for that matter, and couldn't find a clear way to check if a dataframe includes a key and filter based on that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's on way to do it.

```
df2[df2['Product_ID'].isin(df1['Product_ID'].unique())]
```

Get unique `Product_ID` from `df1` and filter those values in `df2['Product_ID']` using `isin()`

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to calculate the intersection of Product_ID's would be using numpy's [`in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html). That gives you a mask.

Then, you simply slice your DF2 using the mask to get the new dataframe you want.

```
import numpy as np
mask = ~np.in1d(DF2.Product_ID, DF1.Product_ID)
DF2 = DF2[mask]
```

Comment: I guess mask should be `mask = np.in1d(DF2.Product_ID, DF1.Product_ID)`